# monthly average of working days data

Tags: r, time, average

I have daily time series (of working days) which I would like to transform in monthly average.

The date format is `%d/%m/%Y`, moreover there are some missing observations (`NA`).

How can I do this?

---

```
# my data
timeseries <- structure(c(309L, 319L, 329L, 339L, 348L, 374L, 384L, 394L, 404L, 413L, 
  2317L, 2327L, 2337L, 2347L, 2356L, 2382L, 2392L, 2402L, 2412L, 2421L, 2447L, 2457L, 
  422L, 432L, 441L, 467L, 477L, 487L, 497L, 506L, 2467L, 2477L, 2487L, 2497L, 2506L,
   2532L, 2542L, 2552L, 2562L, 2571L, 2597L, 2607L, 2617L, 2627L, 2636L, 
  [...]), .Label = c("01/01/1992", "01/01/1993", "01/01/1996", "01/01/1997", "01/01/1998", "01/01/1999", "01/01/2001 [...] ), class = "factor")
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Would be great if you can **dput** your daily times series e.g dput(yourTS)

Comment: How about using the xts `apply.monthly` function: `apply.monthly(x,mean)` where `x` is an xts object

Comment: structure(c(309L, 319L, 329L, 339L, 348L, 374L, 384L, 394L, 404L, 
413L, 2317L, 2327L, 2337L, 2347L, 2356L, 2382L, 2392L, 2402L, 
2412L, 2421L, 2447L, 2457L, 422L, 432L, 441L, 467L, 477L, 487L, 
497L, 506L, 2467L, 2477L, 2487L, 2497L, 2506L, 2532L, 2542L, 
2552L, 2562L, 2571L, 2597L, 2607L, 2617L, 2627L, 2636L, [...]), .Label = c("01/01/1992", "01/01/1993", "01/01/1996", 
"01/01/1997", "01/01/1998", "01/01/1999", "01/01/2001 [...]
), class = "factor")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this many, many ways.  Using base R packages:

```
d <- data.frame(Date=Sys.Date()+1:60, Data=1:60)
tapply(d$Data, format(d$Date,"%Y%m"), mean)
aggregate(d$Data, by=list(Date=format(d$Date,"%Y%m")), mean)
```